# Where should I add the <link rel='stylesheet' line?

Tags: css, wordpress-theming, parent-child

I added the following code in the 'Additional css' section

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
```

I get the result I am looking for. But I'm not satisfied, I want to learn the structure of a web site (I know the code a bit, it's not my main business, but I'd like learn how to do it on my own).

I know that code is contained in the app.css file, but if I add that file, edited by me with the previous code, to my child theme folder, the web site still read the original file. I think it's because of the following code

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='gateway-foundation-style-css'  href='https://(website address)/wp-content/themes/(parent theme name)/app.css?ver=5.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

In blogs and forum I found to add a line (wp_enqueue_style) to function.php, but the file is a little different and it doesn't work.

How can I do?

Comment: Try taking off `?ver=5.2` from the `href` path

Comment: Ok, but I don't know where is that line. I found it with DevTools in (index), I know it's not a real file, and that's not the index.php. so I don't know where I can take off `?ver=5.2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you don't know where to find the file, try creating a new one in the location of your webpage, add the CSS code into a .css file and on your HTML code, add the `<link>` section between your `<head>` section. As you want to learn the structure of a website, the basics of a webpage is pretty much this :

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- Here usually goes <link>, <meta> and <style> -->
</head>
<body>
<!-- Here goes your content, <div>, <span>, <form>, <input>, <h1> and so on -->
</body>
</html>
```

As you're willing to apply your new CSS style to your page, your link to the file goes between the `<head>` section :

```
<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' id='gateway-foundation-style-css'  href='https://(website address)/wp-content/themes/(parent theme name)/app.css?ver=5.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
</head>
```

Comment: I don't know what were wrong before, but after I read your comment I tried to put the link in header.php and now it works.
Thanks!